# How to expose Ganache to local network?

Tags: metamask, ganache

I have a .appx installation of Ganache for Windows. I've made a blockchain on it & deployed a smart contract. Now I want to test it on Android Metamask. But Ganache address is only listening to my PC & it's not usable across all devices connected to same network.

How is it possible to make it open to lan & also connect it to Android Metamask?

Thank you

Answer (score 2):

You can change the `--server` command line argument on `ganache`:

```
Server:
      --server.ws                        Enable a websocket server.                            [boolean] [default: true]
      --server.wsBinary                  Whether or not websockets should response with binary data (ArrayBuffers) or
                                         strings.                     [choices: "true", "false", "auto"] [default: auto]
      --server.rpcEndpoint               Defines the endpoint route the HTTP and WebSocket servers will listen on.
                                                                         [default: "/" (Ethereum), "/rpc/v0" (Filecoin)]
      --server.chunkSize                 For memory and performance reasons ganache may respond with chunked
                                         transfer-encoding over HTTP and fragmented send over WebSockets. This option
                                         allows you to control the approximate size of each chunk.
                                                                                             [number] [default: 1048576]
  -h, --server.host, --host, --hostname  Hostname to listen on.
                                         deprecated aliases: --host, --hostname
                                                                                         [string] [default: "127.0.0.1"]
  -p, --server.port, --port              Port to listen on.
                                         deprecated aliases: --port
                                                                                                [number] [default: 8545]

Options:
  -?, --help     Show help                                                                                     [boolean]
      --version  Show version number                                                                           [boolean]
```

In TCP/IP when you set `--server 0.0.0.0` it will listen to all IP addresses, not just localhost. This includes any public IP addresses your computer has.

This is not limited to `ganache`, but is how TCP/IP protocol and applications work.